# TrueCrypt - Number Instead of File Names

Tags: truecrypt

I was asked to help someone make sense of a TrueCrypt file on a drive. The drive has two files on it: the encrypted file and the installer for version 7.1a.  I am running Windows 7 Pro w/ SP1.  I'm able to open the encrypted file with the supplied software and key, except the folder and file names are numbers now.  The only readable part of the file name is the root folder.

Ex:

> Z:\TEST\93870535\93870536\93870537\94113224\94113225.xls

Is this normal?  How do I restore the path and file names?

There is an HTML document on the drive with a sort of tree view listing with the name and number in brackets.  There is also a CSV log file with "source" and "destination" list.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure: 1. It's a TrueCrypt file? 2. Your key is really decrypting it? If the information (file and folder names in this case) looks messed up, then it's possible that you haven't decrypted it completely.

Comment: @TFM I'm using the supplied software on the hard drive and key I was given.  I've never used TrueCrypt before so I have no idea what to expect.  This is all the client gave me